# Is there an app like Touchwiz Blocking Mode?

Tags: call-screening, sms-blocking

I have a Galaxy Nexus and I want the features of Touchwiz Blocking Mode.

I have done lots of googling but can find only spam call and text blockers.

I want this functionality to block all communications while I sleep except from my fiancee. So basically flight mode but with an exception for one contact.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Ultimate Call Blocker Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=and.blocker.ucb) might be what you are looking for.

You could also try some of these:

- [Call Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flexaspect.android.everycallcontrol)
- [Call Blocker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=embware.phoneblocker)

Comment: Ultimate Call Blocker Free gets mediocre reviews and it sounds unreliable.

Comment: Call Control is incompatible with my Galaxy Nexus and Google Play won't install it. I don't know why

Comment: Call Blocker gets plenty of negative reviews.

Comment: Call blocker has a average rating of 4.3 out of 5, so those are not "plenty" of negative reviews. 5.579 ratings in total, 3.858 5 stars, 811 4 stars, etc.. not so bad I think

Comment: Also, I see Call blocker in my Galaxy nexus as compatible... maybe it is restricted by location instead of Mobile? I'm in spain right now.

Comment: I'm in UK. The first page of reviews shown on Google Play are very mixed. Maybe it got less good recently.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Llama](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama) app, you can set up a “Silent” profile with ring and notification volume set to zero, then add some people to the “noisy” contacts list in the profile to be able to hear rings from them (not sure about SMS). You can either select the needed profile manually, or add rules to switch them automatically (according to the current time or any other events supported by Llama — there are lots of automation possibilities there).

Note that in this case people who call you will just get no answer (although your operator might support some form of call redirection after a timeout). Other call blocking apps may have different behavior (e.g., immediately redirect unwanted calls to voicemail), but Llama cannot do anything with incoming calls except silencing the ring.